# Не видится ничего в Ubuntu для винды

Tags: ubuntu

[image: нету ничего]

Не понимаю как описать даже проблему, запускаю Ubuntu скачанную с Microsoft store и терминал ничего не показывает

Comment: А что терминал должен показать по вашему мнению?

Comment: попробуйте ввести команду какую-нить, `echo "test"`

Comment: Вы случайно вошли в режим выделения текста. Понажимайте правую кнопку мыши чтобы выйти из него

Comment: Правую кнопку мыши понажимал, ничего не изменилось